# Implement Appropriate Single Decimal Place Formatter in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, locale, decimalformat, numberformatter

I need to create a decimal formatter that would display up to 1 decimal digit, with a Locale-compatible seperator.

For example:

```
0 --> 0.0 or 0,0
0.0 --> 0.0 or 0,0
4 --> 4.0 or 4,0
3.5 --> 3.5 or 3,5
```

I need to implement it in Kotlin for Android. I tried initially using `DecimalFormat` but this solution doesn't work when input is "0.0"

```
 DecimalFormat("#.0").format(inputNum.toDouble())
```

What's more appropriate Android-ish way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying various solutions, I figured out the appropriate approach using [NumberFormatter](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/icu/number/NumberFormatter.html) instead of `DecimalFormat` as a recommended approach.

This API offers more features than android.icu.text.DecimalFormat and is geared toward new users of ICU.

```
private fun formatNumber(number: Double) = NumberFormatter.with()
.decimal(NumberFormatter.DecimalSeparatorDisplay.ALWAYS)
.precision(Precision.fixedFraction(1))
.locale(Resources.getSystem().configuration.locales.get(0))
.format(number)
.toString()
```